# Worksheet_change event triggers despite conditions not met

Tags: vba, excel

I have function which marks column D cell change time. Now I want to add another function to worksheet_change event, which would change column E accordingly if specific text is written in column D cell.

Problem I encountered, that column E gets changed every time, despite the fact that conditions are not met (other text is written to column D cell). Can somebody point me to right direction, I am quite new to VBA so maybe I miss something.

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xPaymentColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer

xCellColumn = 4
xTimeColumn = 23
xPaymentColumn = 5

'part for marking date, works as intended
On Error Resume Next
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column

If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    End If
End If

'part for changing column E according column D selection 
'I would like this part to trigger only if text cell in column D changed _
 to "Send request" or "Start evaluation", if any other text is written in column D, _
  column E should remain intact

If Target.Text = "Send request" Or "Start evaluation" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Cells(xRow, xPaymentColumn) = "Yes"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "column E gets changed despite conditions are not met" - can you be more specific? Try commenting out `On Error Resume Next` for starters. Looks ok to me, though you should turn off enableevents before changing the cells in your code.

Comment: text cell in column E gets changed to "Yes", despite the fact, that text in column D got changed to something else than "Send request" or "Start evaluation". I want column E change only then one of these two phrases is entered to column D cell. ill update my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `If` to

```
If Target.Text = "Send request" Or Target.Text = "Start evaluation" Then
```

Your current if-Condition throws an error `Type mismatch`, but you're eating up all errors with the `On Error Resume Next`- message. And so VBA does what you ask: Ignore the runtime error and happily execute the next statement - which is the statement within the If-block.

**A general advice**: Never use `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: ...unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing?

Comment: @Inarion: Right. I use it from time to time as a workaround for missing `try...catch` blocks. But that's not a beginner thingy

Comment: `On Error`, `DisplayAlerts` and **not** having `Option Explicit` probably need to be locked behind some sort of "Expert User Mode" - it would prevent *so* many issues...  xD